# FastReport: Summary on ReportTitle

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have a report with these parts:

ReportTitle
ColumnHeader
MasterData
ColumnFooter
ReportSummary

How can I display sum of a field in MasterData on ReportTitle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two possible ways:

- Via a report variable:

  1. Calculate the total separately.
  2. Pass the total to the report using a report variable (and, possibly, the `TfrxReport.OnGetValue` event).
- Via the `DoublePass` property of the report:

  1. Set the `TfrxReport.EngineOptions.DoublePass` property to `True`.
  2. Calculate the total in the report script and store it to a script variable on the first pass
  3. Fill the memo from the variable on the second pass.

  Use `Engine.FinalPass` in the script to detect whether it's the final (second) pass.

Answer (score 0):

1. Define a variable for sumatory
2. Asign sumatory to variable on first pass of report
3. Show variable on second pass

Or, if the sumatory is result of a query, get this result and show it